# Mounting a pendrive as a swap partition, having problems

Tags: partitioning, mount, swap

The building of one of the softwares I am installing is failing because of the error

> c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

I think this is because I have only 500Mb swap partition. So I am trying to increase it using an external pendrive. I have tried adding

> /dev/sdb1    none    swap    sw    0    0
>
> /dev/sdc1    none    swap    sw    0    0

( since on booting, sometimes the pendrive partition shows /dev/sdb1 while sometimes it shows /dev/sdc1) to the /etc/fstab file but still instead of showing System as Linux swap on using

> fdisk -l

it is showing FAT16. I have also tried

> mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1

so that we create swap on a linux type filesystem,
but it says:

> /dev/sdb1 is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!

I also tried

> sudo swapon /dev/sdb1

but I get

> swapon: /dev/sdb1: read swap header failed: Invalid argument

Please guide me so that I can make a swap partition on my pendrive.

PS: I have root permission.

Comment: `sudo blkid` shows the unique identifiers of the file systems. They won't change unless the file systems are reformatted. In fstab, the notation `UUID=uuid_shown_in_blkid` avoids the problem of the unpredictable /dev/sd?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reformat the entire fat16 drive, the USB should be right on unity sidebar (Or wherever you've tweaked it), right click it and re-format (Use ubuntu, ubuntu formats drives 1000 times the speed of windows, period.)

Re-partition it. (Use ubuntu software center to easily find multiple linux partitioners)

Attempt to put all the files back onto the USB now.

This is the quickest way I can think of to make a USB reformatted and afterword, partition.

Comment: While formatting, Error creating filesystem: The device is busy, Details: /dev/sdb1 is mounted

Comment: Yeah I could format it as you said. Still having some problem partitioning.

Comment: Thanks. I could make a swap partition. I was trying to solve this problem for 4-5 hours. Surely a hint from an expert helps!

Comment: No problem jink! :D Do you mind telling everyone which partition program you used and details on process so anybody with any further issue can get help to? :3

Comment: I used Disk utility in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to format the pendrive and gparted to change the type of partition.

Comment: @NateMcFly how does this create a swap partition on the USB?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest creating a swap partition on a flash device. The read/write rate when swapping would shorten the life of the drive considerably.  But if you like, here how its done:

Open disks from dash, and follow the images below in the order that they are listed:
Click the + sign to create a partition

[image]

Make sure the right type is choose, and name is optional, and them click create

[image]

Click the little wheels, to change the partition type

[image]

Make sure the right type is chosen, and click change

[image]

Notice that the partition type is now Swap

[image]

Click on the little square to mount, and that's it

[image]

Comment: it look nice 1 2 3 boxes.....

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. And by the way, I just needed swap partition on the pendrive for installing [gnuradio](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio) and not for prolonged use, so the flash drive won't get spoilt. There were some problems mounting the pendrive, and I needed a non-wubi ubuntu, so I installed a new ubuntu with dual boot using instructions given [here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/)