# How To Create a Swap Partition on a flash drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, swap

So I am looking to create a swap partition on a flash drive for a program I am working on. We have successfully created the partition on the drive, but when we plug the drive into the router, the router is unable to read the partition. When we plugged the drive into a different computer, we had to manually activate the partition each time. All of the guides we have found on automatically activating the drive only apply to a single computer. Is it possible to have the partition automatically activate on any computer?

Comment: The normal way to activate swap is via a line in the file `/etc/fstab` in the operating system, that you run (or intend to run). You can also activate it 'manually' via `sudo swapon -a` There is a detailed description in `man swapon`. Finally, you can make the system run `sudo swapon -a` automatically in a way that does not cause problems, if the drive with swap is not plugged in.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't suggest creating a swap partition on a flash device. The read/write rate when swapping would shorten the life of the drive considerably.  But if you like, here how its done:

Open disks from dash, and follow the images below in the order that they are listed:
Click the + sign to create a partition

[image]

Make sure the right type is choose, and name is optional, and them click create

[image]

Click the little wheels, to change the partition type

[image]

Make sure the right type is chosen, and click change

[image]

Notice that the partition type is now Swap

[image]

Click on the little square to mount, and that's it

[image]

This answer was copied from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/293863)

Comment: +1 for the warning to avoid swapping to a flash drive. @Terry, Not only will it wear out, it is also very show. But if you use a modern SSD (via USB) the lifetime will be longer (and it is much faster). You get a more reliable swap partition, if you connect a hard disk drive via USB (slower than the SSD, but you can expect a longer life).